# Object with similar attribute names loop, React

Tags: reactjs

I have object with attributes like `tabletA, tabletB, tabletC`, containing allways string.
The same object contains other attributes as well, like `company, phone`.

My goal is to look at attributes in one line, and display only `tablet` attributes, where are `strings`, with `values`.

So I imagine code to look like something like this:

```
{referenceTexts.[tablet].length > 0 && (
    <div>
     referenceTexts.[tablet]
    </div>
 )}
```

Comment: `['tabletA', 'tabletB', 'tabletC'].filter(name => (referenceTexts[name] || '').length > 0).map(name => (<div>{referenceTexts[name]}</div>));` What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Sulthan I have edited my question, not realy i need to display only attributes starting with "tablet". This will display all attributes, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
{Object.entries(referenceTexts)
  .filter(([key, val]) => key.startsWith('tablet') && val.length > 0)
  .map(([_, val]) => (
    <div>{val}</div>
 ))}
```

Comment: not gonna work, i have a other names of atributes, and i need to take only atributes starting with 'tablet'

Comment: @DimaMalko Then use `Object.keys(referenceTexts).filter(name => name.startsWith("tablet"))`.

Comment: Edited my answer to also filter by key

Answer (score 1):

```
const tabletValues = Object.keys(referenceTexts)
   // get keys that start with "tablet"
   .filter(key => key.startsWith('tablet'))
   // get their values
   .map(key => referenceTexts[key])
   // get only values that are not empty
   .filter(value => (value || '').length > 0);
```

Then

```
{tabletValues.map(value => <div>{value}</div>)}
```

Note that the order of the values is undefined so you might want to add some kind of sorting.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully I got you. You want something like this :

```
{Object.keys(referenceTexts).map((key) => {
        if (key.substr(0, 6) === "tablet") {
          return <h1>{referenceTexts[key]}</h1>;
        }
 })}
```